# Can not build a resource-only dll-library (linker errors)

Tags: c++, dll, linker, resources

In MSVC 2017 I've added two bitmaps as resources into a Win32 project
 (in application settings I've selected "DLL").

An `.rc` file was created as a result.

In Linker settings I've set "No Entry Point" to "Yes /NOENTRY"

But when I try to build `.dll`, I get these errors:

[image: errors]

In msvc 2015 I get errors too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add error message as text in the question and not as images. Otherwise search engines won't find the question and it won't be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all the source files (.cpp) from your project. It looks like right now it still compiles some code (which probably originates from precompiled header "stdafx.h").

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! :) You've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating a blank `Dll type` project. It should be `non-MFC` type project.  Now you add resources and set and specify `Yes/NOENTRY` linker option(this you have already done). Now, try to build `dll`. It will work.

Steps to create `dll` is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll).